# How to use Unity 3d and Gnome Shell without any drivers?

Tags: unity, gnome, drivers

Currently I don't have any driver available for the laptop that I use , and because of this I only can use Unity 2d and Gnome Panel.

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 installed and no drivers for both.

I would like to use Unity 3d and Gnome Shell..instead of Unity and Gnome Panel or at least have that option even if computer became a little slower.

Is there a way of enabling Unity 3d and gnome without any driver had been installed?

(my video card is: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10) )

Comment: depends on the graphics card... what is it?  `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)

Comment: oh dear ... you have (i'm sorry to say) ... one of the worst supported linux driver chipsets.  I'm afraid you will only be able to run gnome-panel/unity2d/xfce

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by selecting the best answer (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: i didn't find how can i close a question

Comment: look at the answer - you will see up and down arrows with a number in the middle.  Click the up arrow to vote up.  Click the down arrow to vote down.  You will also see a tick symbol below the down arrow.  Click this to accept an answer (it will highlight as a green tick).

Answer (score 3):

You can't use anything without drivers. However, Linux has lots of drivers built in. Newer AMD Radeon cards doesn't require any extra drivers. Neither does Intel graphics. I'm not entirely sure what the situation is with Nvidia, though I think the newer ones should work well using built-in drivers.

Unity uses Compiz, which will always require hardware acceleration, meaning you do need good drivers, or at the very least, not horrible ones. Gnome Shell uses Mutter, which at least currently has similar requirements. But rumor has it, they're working on removing the necessity of hardware acceleration for Gnome Shell.

---

Since you have a SiS graphics chipset, you will only be able to use the more limited open-source drivers that come by default in a Ubuntu installation.
With this chipset, recommendations on desktop-environments would be the more lightweight variant - for example, gnome-classic, unity-2d or xfce/lxde.

Comment: my card is 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10) so what can i do?