# Is it possible to install drivers used on Windows for Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, windows, wine, playonlinux

There aren't any drivers for the video card on my computer or for SiS in Ubuntu repositories and I know that it is poorly supported or one of least supported. I also have Windows installed and on Windows the drivers are installed and available.

Can I use wine or PlayOnLinux to install those drivers from Windows so that I have the drivers installed on Ubuntu?

Is that possible?

---

I have Ubuntu 12.04 beta so far and Ubuntu 11.10 installed

My video card is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
```

From a previous question that I asked [How to use Unity 3d and Gnome Shell without any drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118716/how-to-use-unity-3d-and-gnome-shell-without-any-drivers)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't do this. What do you mean by no drivers for your computer? Wireless networking, video, Ethernet?

Comment: video card Silicon Integrated Systems

Answer (score 0):

In that case no, you cannot use anything but a pure linux driver for your video card.